# Extracting data from text file with regex

Tags: python, regex

Trying to extract three lists of data from a txt file using regex

File structure = metadata, values (repeat)

```
#
#text
#text
#
9.2318434E-5 -1.3870514E-9 1.0E-4 7.0E-5 9.2318434E-5 9.225606E-5 9.225606E-5 2.5E-4 2.5E-4
9.230842E-5 -1.3756367E-9 1.0E-4 7.0E-5 9.230842E-5 9.225539E-5 9.225539E-5 0.00225 0.00225
9.230592E-5 -1.3935526E-9 1.0E-4 7.0E-5 9.230592E-5 9.2255046E-5 9.2255046E-5 0.00275 0.00275

#
#text
#text
#
9.2318434E-5 -1.3870514E-9 1.0E-4 7.0E-5 9.2318434E-5 9.225606E-5 9.225606E-5 2.5E-4 2.5E-4
9.231593E-5 -1.3816212E-9 1.0E-4 7.0E-5 9.231593E-5 9.225253E-5 9.225253E-5 7.5E-4 7.5E-4
9.230592E-5 -1.3935526E-9 1.0E-4 7.0E-5 9.230592E-5 9.2255046E-5 9.2255046E-5 0.00275 0.00275

#
#text
#text
#
9.2318434E-5 -1.3870514E-9 1.0E-4 7.0E-5 9.2318434E-5 9.225606E-5 9.225606E-5 2.5E-4 2.5E-4
9.231593E-5 -1.3816212E-9 1.0E-4 7.0E-5 9.231593E-5 9.225253E-5 9.225253E-5 7.5E-4 7.5E-4
9.231343E-5 -1.3962527E-9 1.0E-4 7.0E-5 9.231343E-5 9.225581E-5 9.225581E-5 0.00125 0.00125
```

I've been trying the following

```
with open(file) as newfile:
    data = re.findall(r'^([#][\n][0-9])[\s\S]*([\n][\n])$', newfile.read())
```

Each block of data starts with #\n[0-9] and ends with \n\n and then I need to take every character between the start and end hence [\s\S]*. Doesn't seem to be working any help would be great.

Comment: i dont understant if you want the full 3 lines or every number in these 3 lines?

Comment: I expect the output to be a list with three elements containing a string with all the number in that section i.e. mylist = ["numbers\n numbers\n numbers\n", "numbers\n numbers\n numbers\n", "numbers\n numbers\n numbers\n"]

Comment: thanks all working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A side note, you don't need to encase everything in `[]`.

See regex in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/95kDVV/1).

```
^(?<=#\n)\d[^#]*$
```

- `^` assert position at the start of the line
- `(?<=#\n)` positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes matches `#` followed by a newline character `\n`
- `\d` match a digit
- `[^#]*` match any character except `#` any number of times (greedy, so it will try to match as many characters as possible - until it reaches another `#`)
- `$` assert position at the end of the line

---

Alternatively, and very simply, you could probably use `^\d.*` as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/95kDVV/2).

- `^` assert position at the start of the line
- `\d` match a digit
- `.*` match any character (except for line terminators) any number of times

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import re
with open("file.txt") as f:
    t = f.read().strip()

lists = []
m = re.findall(r"^[\d.E\s-]+$", t, re.MULTILINE) # 45 steps
for x in m:
    a = [float(x) for x in " ".join(x.strip().split("\n")).split()]
    lists.append(a)

print(lists)
```

---

Output:

```
[[9.2318434e-05, -1.3870514e-09, 0.0001, 7e-05, 9.2318434e-05, 9.225606e-05, 9.225606e-05, 0.00025, 0.00025, 9.230842e-05, -1.3756367e-09, 0.0001, 7e-05, 9.230842e-05, 9.225539e-05, 9.225539e-05, 0.00225, 0.00225, 9.230592e-05, -1.3935526e-09, 0.0001, 7e-05, 9.230592e-05, 9.2255046e-05, 9.2255046e-05, 0.00275, 0.00275], [9.2318434e-05, -1.3870514e-09, 0.0001, 7e-05, 9.2318434e-05, 9.225606e-05, 9.225606e-05, 0.00025, 0.00025, 9.231593e-05, -1.3816212e-09, 0.0001, 7e-05, 9.231593e-05, 9.225253e-05, 9.225253e-05, 0.00075, 0.00075, 9.230592e-05, -1.3935526e-09, 0.0001, 7e-05, 9.230592e-05, 9.2255046e-05, 9.2255046e-05, 0.00275, 0.00275], [9.2318434e-05, -1.3870514e-09, 0.0001, 7e-05, 9.2318434e-05, 9.225606e-05, 9.225606e-05, 0.00025, 0.00025, 9.231593e-05, -1.3816212e-09, 0.0001, 7e-05, 9.231593e-05, 9.225253e-05, 9.225253e-05, 0.00075, 0.00075, 9.231343e-05, -1.3962527e-09, 0.0001, 7e-05, 9.231343e-05, 9.225581e-05, 9.225581e-05, 0.00125, 0.00125]]
```

---

Demo:

- [Python Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/17jd)
- [Regex Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/RwOBq7/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem without using regex at all if you wish. As you only want to read lines which do not start with symbol `#`, you can just read lines from file and check whether they start with `#` or not. Then strip the line and split it from spacing to get all the numbers as string.

Here is an example using list comprehension:

```
numbers = []
with open(file) as newfile:
    numbers += [number for line in newfile.readlines() if not line.startswith('#') for number in line.strip().split()]
newfile.close()
print(numbers) # list of all the numbers as strings
```